# Cannot find name WebGLObject Typscript issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I run

`ng serve command`

I am getting error

> Cannot find name WebGLObject.

Answer (score 1):

Install @types/webgl2 package in your project using

```
npm install @types/webgl2
```

All your issues will hopefully get fixed.